# How to ignore empty lines while getting integer input in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that we can skip any number of empty lines while getting string input using this:

```
words = raw_input()
while words in ('\n' or '\r\n'):
    words = raw_input()
```

what will be the procedure to do the same, if the input is of integer type?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with an example? Your title seems different from the contents.

Comment: `('\n' or '\r\n')` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If preceding and trailing whitespace characters are not meaningful I'd suggest combination of `.strip()` method and check for truthfulness (as empty strings are falsy)

```
words = raw_input()
while not words.strip():
    words = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

This would ask for new input if the input string given is a blank line or an integer number.

```
words = raw_input()
while words in ['\n','\r\n'] or words.isdigit():
    words = raw_input()
```

**OR**

This would ask for new input if the input string given is an integer number.

```
words = raw_input()
while words.isdigit():
    words = raw_input()
```